# See iAd Revenue in the new iTunes Connect layout?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'd like to know how I can see my iAd revenue in the "new" iTC layout? Two days ago there was a link in iTC (I think the label even said iAd revenue or stats), but now all I have is the new iAd Workbench.
Do you know where the new page for iAd revenue is?

Answer (score 11):

Looks like apple hides the url. After log in iTunes connect, visit https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/ directly.

Update:
visit https://iad.apple.com/

Comment: While this is beyond weird, the URL worked... thank you!

Comment: Are we supposed to guess that by ourself ? Thanks @Vince !

Comment: It is unfathomable!!!